# How should be the definition of a module with a child subclass to make Rubocop rule Style/ClassAndModuleChildren pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

Basically I have this.

```rb
module EcommerceApi
  class Application < Rails::Application
  end
end
```

But Rubocop still complaining:

```rb
Use compact module/class definition instead of nested style.Style/ClassAndModuleChildren
```

How should be the definition in this case?

Comment: It's saying to use `module EcommerceApi::Application < Rails Application` but this doesn't actually work in all cases, in order for it to work you would need to make sure `module EcommerciApi` is already defined elsewhere.

Comment: Ye it doesn't work for me in this case.
I'll disable the rule for this file, then. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell that cop to shove off [by ignoring it](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html). This cop actually conflicts with the Ruby Style guide that Rubocop is supposed to enforce:

> Define (and reopen) namespaced classes and modules using explicit
> nesting. Using the scope resolution operator can lead to surprising
> constant lookups due to Ruby’s lexical scoping, which depends on the
> module nesting at the point of definition.
>
> - https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Basically what thats saying is that if you use `class EcommerceApi::Application` instead of explicit nesting the module nesting inside there is going to be `[EcommerceApi::Application]` instead of `[EcommerceApi, EcommerceApi::Application]`. Thus if you reference `Foo` you won't get `EcommerceApi::Foo` but instead `::Foo` from the global namespace (or a missing constant error).